# .attr() checkbox issue with jQuery v1.9.1

Tags: jquery, version

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<span id="test">Click here</span>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#test").click(function () {
    if ($(":checkbox").attr("checked") == undefined) {
        $(":checkbox").attr("checked", "checked")
    } else {
        $(":checkbox").removeAttr("checked")
    }
});
```

Fiddle: [Link - v1.8.3](http://jsfiddle.net/pYQJt/1/)

This works just fine, but, if I change the jquery version to 1.9.1, the checkbox doesn't get checked anymore. What is the issue?

Fiddle: [Link - v.1.9.1](http://jsfiddle.net/pYQJt/2/)

Although the `inspect element` shows the checkbox is toggling the attribute, if I do a `$(":checkbox").is(":checked")` in the console, I get `false` as the output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`checked` is a property, you should use `prop` method, when a boolean attribute like `disabled` or `checked` is set to an element, the value is mapped to the relevant DOM property of the element(*browser do this*) and `attr` and `removeAttr` methods do not change the properties of an element, as of jQuery 1.6 for modifying properties, `prop` method should be used instead of `attr`.

```
$("#test").click(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', function(i, state){
        return !state;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3rQvj/

Comment: +1 In addition for OP's benefit, here is the links to the [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [**prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) documentation which has a lot of details and examples on HTML elements behaviour and jQuery changes when using `attr()` or `prop()` and which is recommended for specific types of elements.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue and you should refer below link to get proper idea
http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-
Hope it solves your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a label? That way it would work without javascript.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test" /><label for="test">Click me</label>
```

Comment: it's a part of a bigger thing I'm doing, the logic is the same however.